# Erro com TimerTask: Looper.prepare() not called

Tags: java, android

Recebi este erro.

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Objectivo é repetir a função que recebe o mapa de 1000 em 1000 milésimas de segundo.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      try {
                                          recebemapa();
                                      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                      }
                                  }

                              },
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
                0,

//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
                1000);
```

Eu chamo este código no método `OnCreate()`

Comment: O método `recebemapa()` acede a métodos de alguma *View*?

Comment: Sim tem acesso a métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponho que o problema possa estar em o método `recebemapa()` ter código que só pode ser executado na *UI thread*.
Se assim for use o método `runOnUiThread()` para executar esse código:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
              {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      try {
                          recebemapa();
                      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              });
      }

 },0, 1000);
```

Uma alternativa([talvez melhor](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/android/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)) é usar um *Handler*(neste caso tem de ser criado na *UI Thread*, que é o caso de onCreate())

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            recebemapa();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso era a função para ir buscar ao servidor o json já resolvi obrigado